# Alter table and add new column with default value via a function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, alter-table

I am trying to update a table in Oracle. The table is created using following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID_NUM INTEGER,
    NAME INTEGER,
    VALUE INTEGER,
    ITEMS_NUM INTEGER,
)
```

And there were some data injected into this table. Now, I need to update the table to change the **ID_NUM** column as VARCHAR and add formatted UUID as default value.

I have followed the queries given below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RANDOM_UUID RETURN VARCHAR IS
  V_UUID VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(RAWTOHEX(SYS_GUID()), '([A-F0-9]{8})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{12})', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') INTO V_UUID FROM DUAL;
  RETURN V_UUID;
END RANDOM_UUID;

ALTER TABLE TEST 
    DROP COLUMN ID_NUM;

ALTER TABLE TEST 
    ADD ID_NUM VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT random_uuid()  NOT NULL;
```

It gives an error as `SQL Error [4044] [42000]: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here`
I have executed and validated the function using following command and it gives a valid formatted UUID.

```
SELECT RANDOM_UUID() FROM DUAL;
```

What could be the issue in the **ALTER table** statement. Can't we use a function for setting default value in Oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve it using the `default clause` on the `column` but without `function` (just replace the `function` call with the content of the `function` in `default` clause) as following. (Please note that the `User functions` are not allowed in the `default clause`)

> ```
> ALTER TABLE TEST 
>     ADD ID_NUM VARCHAR(255)
>     DEFAULT REGEXP_REPLACE(RAWTOHEX(SYS_GUID()), '([A-F0-9]{8})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{12})', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5')
>     NOT NULL;
> ```

I have prepared the [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d19897b27b1d354f7f6b8d8b15559df2) to show you the error with `function` and success without `function`.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PL/SQL functions in the default expression. But it can be a SQL function.Here's an extract from the [19c Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6):

Default column values are subject to the following restrictions:

- A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or
  to other columns, the pseudocolumns LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date
  constants that are not fully specified.

And here's an example using a sql function:

```
    SQL> create table tc (c1 number default sqrt(2));

    Table TC created.
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value has to be an actual value, not a function.